# orientation change sound

Tags: java, android

Good morning,

We have developed an android app, and I have been charged with finding out how to remove the undesired behavior of a notification sound every time that the screen orientation changes. Obviously this behavior only exists on devices running OS version 3.2.3 or later.

I have read several posts that indicate that this can be turned off by unchecking USB Debugging in the Settings --> Developer options, however this option is not checked and none of the other apps that are on any of our Android devices make this notification sound upon orientation change.

The application does require there to be a notification when a "message is received" (the app connects to a webservice and gets new messages from the service every so often). So this would rule out any solution that disabled notifications.

Thus far, I have tried several potential solutions:
1) When a message is received, instantiate a new NotificationManager, and after the notification is sounded, destroy the NotificationManager.

```
if(MessageReceived == true) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    messageNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
}
showNotification();
messageNotifyManager = null;
```

2) I realize that an orientation change is essentially the view being destroyed and re-created. I put set a flag in the initial onCreate method and checked to see if that flag had value before recreating the Notification Manager.

```
public static int Flag = 0; 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    if(Flag == 0) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
  messageNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        Flag = 1;
    } 
}
```

3) In the application's main class, I created a public OrientationEventListener property and then set its value in the onCreate method, disabling it immediately. When that didn't disable the sound I tried disabling the property in every class that referenced the application's main class.

```
public OrientationEventListender listener;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appContext = getApplicationContext();
    GetPreferences();
    //...
    listener = new OrientationEventListener(appContext){
        public void onOrientationChanged(int Orientation){
        }
    };
    listener.disable();
}
```

Now, as you can probably tell, I am very new to Android development. I assume that this solution is something so simple that everyone knows, and that is why there are no answers anywhere handy on the web. But any help with this simple problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if the activity is being destroyed or recreated can you not change that behaviour in the manifest by using android:launchMode = "singleTask"

Comment: Unfortunately, the launch mode is already set to "singleTask". Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by modifying the AndroidManifest, adding the following tag to each activity: android:configChanges="orientation"